# error message when deploying app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I am new to Ruby on Rails. Doing the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.

I use Cloud 9 as host, and Bitbucket for version control, and deployment through Heroku.
I have tried to install Postgresql into my project instead of sqlite3 because I know Heroku requires it. But somehow, and somewhere in my files I fail.

Can anyone help?

When I run:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

I get this error:

```
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:
remote:        /tmp/build_169ab9dc473338103fb7830819856f04/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_169ab9dc473338103fb7830819856f04/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
remote:
remote:
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_169ab9dc473338103fb7830819856f04/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_169ab9dc473338103fb7830819856f04/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to stormy-shelf-7526.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/stormy-shelf-7526.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to.....
```

Comment: Can you post your current `Gemfile` so I can add more help to my answer?

Comment: Look into this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Comment: Do you know how I can add my Gemfile on here? Rick I have followed that instruction. Still not working..

Comment: @Cathrin edit your post with the information

Comment: @Cathrin Do you follow all those steps of document? And which type of problem you are getting now? Need more details on this.

Comment: Ensure that sqlite3 no longer exists in your Gemfile.lock

Comment: Gemfile:source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.6'

gem 'pg'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

Comment: Remove sqlite3  from your Gemfile.lock

Comment: I did remove sqlite3 for Gemfile.lock..

Comment: delete Gemfile.lock file and do bundle install again and let me know

Comment: Well, Gemfile.lock too long to attach, but have run bundle install, and I have deleted sqlite3 from it, but cannot delete the whole file?

Comment: So what you are getting now?

Comment: when doing git push heroku master I get the same error..

Comment: I am in the early state, so should I just delete the whole project and start over? Just curious if it can be something else that is happening?

Comment: Have you changed adapter to `adapter: postgresql` in your database.yml file?

Comment: Yes I have changed to adapter: postgresql

Comment: @Cathrin I don't mean for you to post it as a comment here. You can edit your own post and add the additional information rather than commenting it.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you cannot use `sqlite3` on Heroku.

What the error means is that your `Gemfile` contains `sqlite3` as part of the bundle process for production. What you need to do is to wrap `sqlite3` in a `development` and/or `test` group and make sure you have the `pg` gem outside of those groups.

Comment: Problem is, I have done this in my files within Cloud 9. I have run bundle install, and I have followed a tutorial via heroku.com on how to delete sqlite3 and install postgresql.

Comment: once I see your Gemfile, I'll be able to give you a bit more insight.